# how to adjust ethereum transaction's nonce

Tags: transactions, ethereum, nonce

In the process of developing the ethereum dapp, I tested the load and there was a nonce error.
When building a rawTx, I used `web3.getTransactionCount("accountAddress", 'pending')` as the nonce of the transaction.
I didn't think there was going to be a nonce error, because I didn't use `web3.getTransactionCount("accountAddress")` as the nonce of the transaction, but it happened.
I wonder how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correct. The question lacks context information to tell what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing eth object call after web3 and don't forget await key word

```
await web3.eth.getTransactionCount('address', 'pending')
```